# Youtube Data API v3 My list of Subscriber is not complete

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get a list of all my subscribers using Youtube Data Api. But a large amount of my public subscribers aren't appearing.

```
# Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
# *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

api_service_name = "youtube"
api_version = "v3"
client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

# Get credentials and create an API client
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file, scopes)
credentials = flow.run_console()
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

curSubDicList = []
nextPageToken = ""

while TRUE:    #Loop through all subs and fill out the curSubDicList var

    request = youtube.subscriptions().list(part="subscriberSnippet", mySubscribers=True, maxResults=50, pageToken=nextPageToken, order="alphabetical")
    response = request.execute()

    for x in response["items"]:
        print(x["subscriberSnippet"]["title"])
        subDic = { "title" : x["subscriberSnippet"]["title"], "channelId" : x["subscriberSnippet"]["channelId"], "pfp" : x["subscriberSnippet"]["thumbnails"]["default"]["url"]}
        curSubDicList.append(subDic)

    if "nextPageToken" in response:
        nextPageToken = response["nextPageToken"]
    else:
        break
```

I loop through using each new `nextPageToken` till there isn't one. But for some reason a lot of my public subscribers aren't appearing. I print out my subs to my file `subs.json`

```
jsonSubsTxt = open("subs.json", "w", encoding="utf-8")
curSubDicListJsonStr = json.dumps(curSubDicList)
jsonSubsTxt.write(curSubDicListJsonStr)
jsonSubsTxt.close()
```

I know that a lot of my public subs are missing by using Youtube Studio's built in subscriber viewer, and `CTRL + F`ing for them in the `subs.json`. I have a 2nd youtube account called "LowerLevelLemmy" I made sure that my subscriptions were public and subscribed to myself. I appear as a sub in YT Studio, but not in my `subs.json`. Here's images of what I mean:

[My 2nd channel appears in YT Studio as a public sub.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CROnb.png)

[But CTRL Fing for it shows no results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUgDt.png)

Sometimes `CTRL+F`ing someone I see as a sub in YT Studio works but most times it doesn't. When their username doesn't come up with a match, I try searching with their channel ID, but that doesn't work either.

I'm new to Youtube Data Api and this is my first time submitting a question to Stack Over Flow. I hope I did everything right. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Probably an error from YouTube itself. Consider post this issue at [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803). Also, I saw you're querying your subscribers with `order="alphabetical"` - try to remove this option and try again - YouTube Data API have some issues with pagination and results, so, maybe the error is in their response - it might be worth try and add the test you made in the ticket you are going to create in Issue Tracker. Please, once you posted the ticket, click the "star" (*for highlight your ticket*) and also post the URL here.

Comment: Please, once you posted the ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803), click the "star" (*for highlight your ticket*) and also post the URL or the created ticked here. Best of luck.

Comment: Here's the [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220183528) to my summited issue. Removing the `order="alphabetical"` didn't change anything unfortunately. Maybe the YT data API only shows recent subscribers. @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes